# writing unit test cases

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, mstest

In my project we are dealing with database (SQL server 2008). Reading, inserting, deleting and updating data. Some of the SQL script is created by xml automation tool and some are manually written by developer.
Most of the times we face issues by manual missing entry and automated generated scripts.
I would lie to write unit test cases for that scripts just to take care so that we will not face issues after checkin the code.
so my question is that is it a good way to write unit test cases for these scripts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your sql then I would suggest to have a look at the [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) which include database UTs which can be run via Visual Studio 2010 and 2012